Ставится ли в таком случае вопросительный знак после кавычек?
Какой знак следует поставить в этом предложении после прямой речи, учитывая, что само предложение вопросительное, а прямая речь восклицательная? Ставится ли в таком случае вопросительный знак после кавычек?
Кто захватил эти земли и сказал: "Вы будете жить по моим правилам!"(?)


Ставится ли в таком случае вопросительный знак после кавычек?

Да, ставится.
Восклицательный знак относится к цитате, а вопросительный к словам автора, ко всему предложению-вопросу:
Кто захватил эти земли и сказал: "Вы будете жить по моим правилам!"?

4. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный/восклицательный знак, то после кавычек он не повторяется: Читали ли вы роман «Что делать?»
Неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста, ставятся и после закрывающих кавычек:
Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?».
В каком стихотворении М. Ю. Лермонтова есть слова: «Люблю Отчизну я, но странною любовью!»?

Кавычки и другие знаки (справочник Розенталя)
